# Where does Zabbix store the Dashboard's Favorite objects (maps, screens and graphs)?

Tags: zabbix

I've looked at the database schema, but found nothing related. I've looked at the PHP code for the dashboard page at `/usr/share/zabbix/dashboard.php`, but they use some code I can't quite grasp.

For example:

```
CFavorite::add('web.favorite.screenids', $id, $favouriteObject)
```

So, I understand it has to somewhere link that to each user profile. Here are the columns for the profile table, but I can't see where else in the database this information would be kept.

```
mysql> describe profiles;
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| profileid | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| userid    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| idx       | varchar(96)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| idx2      | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| value_id  | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| value_int | int(11)             | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| value_str | varchar(255)        | NO   |     |         |       |
| source    | varchar(96)         | NO   |     |         |       |
| type      | int(11)             | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've identified the correct table. There was partial documentation about this table at https://zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/DB_schema/3.4/profiles , I added more detail just now.

An example of the meaningful fields when a screen favourite entry is stored:

```
MariaDB [zabbix]> select userid,idx,value_id,source,type from profiles
    -> where idx like 'web.favorite.screenids';
+--------+------------------------+----------+----------+------+
| userid | idx                    | value_id | source   | type |
+--------+------------------------+----------+----------+------+
|     45 | web.favorite.screenids |       16 | screenid |    1 |
+--------+------------------------+----------+----------+------+
```

Comment: a user asked me to rearrange the order of his favorites. I suggested he deleted all links and re-add them in the desired order. If I read it correctly, the value_id field is the Screen Id (or Map Id, etc). In that case, is it possible to rearrange the fav screens for example? Should I use the profileid to gain insight on that?

Comment: I see that maybe the magnitude of the ``profielid`` determines the order. If this is so, can I just do an UPDATE commando on the desired row to change the order of presentation?

Comment: Reordering is a bit different question, I'd suggest asking it separately - and make sure to mention which version of Zabbix you are using.

Comment: Yes, sir. Here's the [link to the new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54306710/how-to-reorder-zabbix-dashboards-favorite-objects-maps-screens-and-graphs) and thanks for sharing your knowledge with us.