# How to reorder Zabbix Dashboard's Favourite objects (maps, screens and graphs)?

Tags: zabbix

How can a front end user reorder his favorite graphs shortcuts on the Zabbix Dashboard page?

If it's not possible, how can the admin do that from the database?

The relevant information is stored on the `profiles` table ([refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217491/where-does-zabbix-store-the-dashboards-favorite-objects-maps-screens-and-grap)). I've looked at it and concluded that the magnitude of the `profileid` column seems to be the metric that determines the order of showing in the dashboard.

But what is the best way to reorder that? Can one do `update` commands to change the `profileid` numbers safely? Is there other restrictions to do that, other possible implications?

Note: Zabbix version is 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in Zabbix 2.4 the dashboard favourite entries are sorted by the `profileid` field. You can modify it and change the order of the entries, just make sure to use a non-existent `profileid` for the temporary changes.

With entries A=4 and B=5, one could set `profileid` of A to 6, B to 4 and finally A to 5, thus reversing the order - if the value of 6 was not in use already.

Having said that, note that somewhere between Zabbix 2.4 and 4.0 the sort order has changed to an alphabetic one. All your changes here would become useless once you upgrade.

Comment: So, on Zabbix 4.0, users won't be able to change the order of their favourites at all. That's  a little bit unfortunate. Is that by design? Many users I see like to cluster related fav objects together (specially when they have more than 10 favs).

Comment: Probably by design / oversight. Consider searching for existing feature requests. If none found, creating a new one might be a good idea.